# How to skip fwrite() for x lines

Tags: php, iteration

I'm creating PHP program which should find in *.txt file line that starts with word "tak" and skip that program from rewriting  it to the next *.txt file. So what I want to achieve now is prevent it from writing, for example, 2 more lines after line that started with "tak" word. Here is my CODE:

```
<?php
$file2 = fopen("out.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$handle = fopen("plik.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if (strpos($line, 'tak') === 0) {
            echo 'found<br/>';
        }
        else {
            fwrite($file2, $line);
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    echo "can't read the file";
}

?>
```

Comment: It checks whether or not line starts with "tak"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by keeping `boolean` and `integer` variable to count the number of occurrence. Like this,

```
<?php
$file2 = fopen("out.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$handle = fopen("plik.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    $stopWriteLines=false;
    $max_line_skip=2;
    // Taking above two variables for our logic.

    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        if($stopWriteLines) {
            $max_line_skip--;   
        }
        // Above condition check if we found tak in line then decrements the skip lines count.

        if (strpos($line, 'tak') === 0) {
            echo 'found<br/>';
            $stopWriteLines=true; // Setting Boolean variable to skip writing lines.
        }
        else {
            if(!$stopWriteLines) { // will write only if Boolean variable is set to true.
                fwrite($file2, $line);
            }
        }

        if($max_line_skip==0) {
           $stopWriteLines=false;
        }

        // Above condition will make Boolean variable false after skipping 'n' lines.
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo 'OK';
}
else {
    echo "can't read the file";
}
?>
```

Please check the explanations in code for better understanding of respected code sections.

Comment: This only skips lines after first "tak"

Comment: `if (strpos($line, 'tak') === 0) {` As we have added this in while loop, this should work for every line.

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work for me. It just skips the first 2 lines after first "tak".

Comment: Update the question with testcase, I'll try that out.

Answer (score 1):

I think using `file`, a `for` loop, and `file_put_contents` would work and be simpler.

```
$file2 = "out.txt";
//$file = file($file2) or die("Unable to open file!");
$file = array('asdf',
'asdf',
'asdf',
'tak',
'1',
'2',
'3',
'4');
file_put_contents($file2, ''); // truncate file;
for($i = 0; $i < count($file); $i++) {
    $line = $file[$i];
    if (strpos($line, 'tak') === 0) {
        echo 'found<br/>';
        $i = $i + 2;
    } else {
  //     file_put_contents($file2, $line, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
       echo $line;
    }
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/597694

Output (kinda messy but gets the point `tak`, `1`, and `2` skipped):

```
asdfokasdfokasdfokfound<br/>ok3ok4ok
```

Comment: so I replaced you array with my txt file and it didnt work

Comment: Did you just uncomment `//$file` and remove the array below? `$file` needs to be an array of each line, is that what you put there?

Comment: Does it just go into the else block on every iteration or what happens?

Comment: It doesn't even start

Comment: What does `print_r($file);` give you?

Comment: Okay, add it, it is for debugging.

Comment: It says nothing. I have only "Unable to open file!" on my screen. So I guess it cannot be loaded

Comment: Yea, maybe use absolute path.